# get image from uploaded video codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ffmpeg-php, video-thumbnails

I am using Codeigniter to develop a website in which one of the features is to upload videos to a folder. There will be a gallery that contains several thumbnails corresponding to each video. Those thumbnails would work as a links to the corresponding video.

I created the gallery following this tutorial([code is available here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-from-scratch-file-uploading-and-image-manipulation--net-9452)):

Only changed the accepted files and added to the htaccess these lines:

php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M

Here is my question: is it possible to use the present code to get the thumbnails (because I can do that if I upload images) or do I have to use ffmpeg or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use FFMPEG-PHP (or similar) to get a thumbnail from a video.

Part of this guide explains how it's done: 
https://arjunphp.com/upload-video-convert-flv-using-ffmpeg-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

For pure PHP code I have found the following tutorial on Youtube quite useful as a starting point for my own CI project.

[FFMPEG and PHP](https://youtu.be/xcdTIDHm4KM?list=PLf1QYWO6pRZiBa_7JlpR-ejHaIHzFblMq)